# Binding Combobox to Object Datasource

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I've got a form bound to an object datasource. It has one text box and one combo box. I set up one binding source for the main object and one binding source for the combo box. When I run the form, the text box is bound correctly, and the list of values in the combo box is bound correctly, but the ValueMember of the combo box isn't working correctly.

The combo box shows the correct list, but it's selected index is 0 instead of what it should be 2. When I change the value in the text box, it's bound object's Property.Set method is called correctly, but the same Property.Set method is not called for the combo box.

I know I can hack up the OnSelectedIndex change methods in the form, but I would like to know what I am doing wrong in just using the Bindings.

Here is the code on the form:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim NameValueBindingSource1 As New BindingSource()
    Dim WorkOrderBindingSource1 As New BindingSource

    'Create main object to bind to
    Dim wo As New WorkOrder
    wo.WOIndex = "2012-0111"
    wo.WorkOrderType = 3

    'Create list object for combo box
    Dim NameValues As BindingList(Of NameValue)
    NameValues = FillNameValueList()

    'Bind Text Box to Binding Source
    WorkOrderBindingSource1.DataSource = wo
    WOIndexTextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", WorkOrderBindingSource1, "WOIndex")

    'Bind Combo Box to Binding Source
    NameValueBindingSource1.DataSource = NameValues
    WorkOrderTypeCombo.DataSource = NameValueBindingSource1
    WorkOrderTypeCombo.DisplayMember = "Value"
    WorkOrderTypeCombo.ValueMember = "Code"

End Sub

Function FillNameValueList() As BindingList(Of NameValue)
    Dim bl As New BindingList(Of NameValue)
    Dim nv As NameValue

    nv = New NameValue
    bl.Add(New NameValue("Short", 0))
    bl.Add(New NameValue("Middle", 1))
    bl.Add(New NameValue("Long", 2))
    bl.Add(New NameValue("Very Long", 3))

    Return bl
End Function
End Class
```

Here's the code for the main object - "WorkOrder"

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class WorkOrder
    Implements IEditableObject
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private mWOIndex As String
    Private mWorkOrderType As Integer

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Property WOIndex As String
        Get
            Return mWOIndex
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            mWOIndex = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("WOIndex"))
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property WorkOrderType As Integer
        Get
            Return mWorkOrderType
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            mWorkOrderType = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("WorkOrderType"))
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub BeginEdit() Implements System.ComponentModel.IEditableObject.BeginEdit
    End Sub
    Public Sub CancelEdit() Implements System.ComponentModel.IEditableObject.CancelEdit
    End Sub
    Public Sub EndEdit() Implements System.ComponentModel.IEditableObject.EndEdit
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here's the code for the object used in the combo box

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class NameValue
    Implements IEditableObject
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private mValue As String
    Private mCode As Integer

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Property Code As Integer
        Get
            Return mCode
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            mCode = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Code"))
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Value As String
        Get
            Return mValue
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            mValue = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub BeginEdit() Implements System.ComponentModel.IEditableObject.BeginEdit
    End Sub
    Public Sub CancelEdit() Implements System.ComponentModel.IEditableObject.CancelEdit
    End Sub
    Public Sub EndEdit() Implements System.ComponentModel.IEditableObject.EndEdit
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(InitValue As String, InitCode As Integer)
        Value = InitValue
        Code = InitCode
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have a lot of things going on here. It's very hard to follow for me to help you. Can you strip it down to the bare essentials of the problem? Maybe you'll find a solution by just doing that.

Comment: I'm not sure I can simplify it any more. The minimum problem requires 2 objects, a binding list, and a form. The binding seems to work ok using datasets, but seems to fail using objects as the data source. The code for the form is pretty straight forward (IMHO). I will be glad to explain any part of the code as necessary if that would help.

Comment: I don't see where you set the actual databinding for the combobox. Is it just missing from your code sample ?

Comment: The combo box binding occurs at:
    NameValueBindingSource1.DataSource = NameValues
    WorkOrderTypeCombo.DataSource = NameValueBindingSource1

Comment: Ok, you're confirming that it's not just missing from your sample code, so see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are merely assigning the DataSource to the ComboBox, but you're not establishing any DataBinding for it.

You need a line like this (using C# here):

```
WorkOrderTypeCombo.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", WorkOrderBindingSource1, "WorkOrderType", true));
```

Hope this helps